# bazaar: I do not want to commit changes to file permissions

Tags: cygwin, commit, bazaar

I am wanting to commit some changes I have made, but somehow on my Cygwin system, `bzr diff` shows that every single file had the executable permission switched on ("+x"). How can I commit everything *except* any file permission changes?

In my case, the easier method (which I'm about to try) is to globally change all files to lose executable permission. However, I still would like a general answer to the problem of how to selectively not commit file permission changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change the files to no longer be executable by running "bzr revert" on them. Alternatively, you could just run something like "chmod -R a-X ." to remove the executable bit from all files.

There is no way in Bazaar to only commit the content changes of a file and not the metadata changes at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Changing it globally is probably your best bet. It is also a problem when mounting fat32 partitions (eg. usb keys) under linux.
[There is a bug for this.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/240294) I got [sort of halfway fixing it](https://code.launchpad.net/~amanica/bzr/supports_executable-detect-based-on-fs-240294) so that it will be auto detected, but dirstate was a bit difficult to work with and then I ran out of time.